# Neither latexdef.exe nor texdef.exe run, although they are installed. How's that?

Tags: miktex, texdef

I have these packages installed and both latexdef.exe and texdef.exe (I know they are actually the same thing) issue the following error messages:

```
(la)texdef: The script could not be found.
(la)texdef: Data: scriptEngine="perl", name="latexdef", path="scripts/texdef/perl/texdef.pl"
```

It's a false message, since 'texdef.pl' is in fact located in scripts/texdef/perl/ folder (and also in its parent folder scripts/texdef/, in which the package was initially installed!!)

Any idea how to make this work?

Environment: MiKTeX 2.9.6520

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! To you have a perl distribution installed?

Comment: I made a bug report: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/14.

Comment: Bernard: Yes, I have Perl installed. I have also put the path of perl.exe in the PATH.

Ulrike: I read your bug report. Thank you. It refers to one of the problems: that it looks in the wrong folder. What about the fact that it doesn't find texdef.pl in neither of the folders? That, I believe, is the most serious and fatal problem.

Comment: The script is found if you update the fndb. But `latexdef` doesn't work, only `texdef -t latex`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, indeed, I run 'initexmf.exe -u' and (la)texdef.exe now works. Thanks!  BTW, Why didn't you offer this solution as a regular answer so that I (and other) can upvote you?